# What is a good way of working with variables in 8 bit blocks?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, programming-languages, language-design

I'm playing around with a toy language design of mine and I have a few problems.  I would like it to have variables specified in bit length.  So, for example, one declares the variables like so:

```
byte value;
two_bytes value;
```

Now, here's my problem.  I'm trying to make an interpreter for the language in C (or C++).  My understanding of C/C++ is that their variable types are guaranteed to be at least a minimum size, but they can be larger (ie, a char will be at least 8 bits, but some implementations will have a 16 bit char).

How can I write an interpreter in C/C++ that deals only with specific lengths of bits?  Is the only way to have an array of booleans or to set up bitfields for something like the char type?

Comment: The question is why you want to save memory. Do you target to extremeley embedded applications? The time to get one bit out of one byte is almost equal to get an 8 bit unsigned char. The char you can use directly in 

    char bit;
    bit = get(3);
    if (bit)
     ...

To use a bit out of a char you even have to mask it.

Comment: Why would it be a problem if the size of a given type is larger than what you need?

Comment: Which is your preference, C or C++?

Comment: `bool` has size 1. It's not individual bits.

Comment: @Pubby: Not necessarily.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What do you mean? I can't imagine anything else, save for the few instances where it can be optimized out.

Comment: @Pubby: The standard explicitly says that `sizeof(bool)` is not required to be 1.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What use would it be otherwise? `char` is always 1, and bool can always be represented as a `char`.

Comment: @Pubby: Perhaps by the native size of the platform, to make access faster.

Comment: @glglgl, I prefer C++, but am comfortable in C.

Comment: @Pubby: In some platforms `sizeof(bool) == 4`, you never know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

stdint header is what you need:

```
#include <cstdint>
std::int32_t x; // 32 bits signed
std::uint16_t y; // 16 bits unsigned
```

Comment: If you include `cstdint`, then you should use `std::int32_t`. The language allows but does not require implementations to provide the types in the global namespace, and that makes your example non-portable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want primitive types, then most compilers should offer `<stdint.h>` (or `<cstdint>`), which contains types such as `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`.

If you want obscure sizes (like e.g. `uint13_t`), you're probably best just using a larger standard size.  If you need to save space, you might look into `std::bitset`, but this will probably be substantially slower for most operations.

Answer (score 3):

If I get you right,

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t my_byte_var;
int16_t my_signed_2byte_var;
```

could be your way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use an unsigned int to hold something of say, 8 bits, and still use bitwise operators on it such as shifting (>>).  Controlling the length would simply be some sort of inserted logic.  8 bits can be no larger than 2^8th - 1 (255).

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure of the existing bit length, and want to pass it into another value to parse it as such, you can simply do the following:

```
char a;
uint8_t b[4];

b = a;
```

Now you can access the components of a depending on the length, up to a maximum size of 32 bits, though a char is never going to be 32 bits, I'm just using it for examples sake.